# Checking elements' suffix within a list

Tags: python, string, list, tuples

I would need to create a new column in a csv file looking at the suffix of elements in the first column ('Subject'). Specifically, if an element of the first column ends with `_pol` then I need to add "`politics`" to the corresponding row in the new column; if it ends with `_sport` then I add "`sports`"; if it ends with `_econ` then I add "`economics`"; and so on.

The elements in the first column look like

```
subject_pol
subj_econ
homework_sport
...
```

What I would like to do is to compare the end of the elements to the suffix in a list:

```
suffix= ['_pol','_econ','_sport','_maths','_computerscience', 'others']
```

in order to assign the corresponding field:

```
   field=['politics', 'economics', 'sports','mathematics','computer science', 'others']
```

I wrote the following code but it does not check if an element ends with a value from the list above.

```
with open('/parsed.csv','r') as csvinput:
    with open('/parsed_out.csv', 'w') as csvoutput:
        writer = csv.writer(csvoutput, lineterminator='\n')
        reader = csv.reader(csvinput)

        all = []
        row = next(reader)
        row.append('Subjects')
        all.append(row)

        for row in reader: 
            if [row[0].endswith(i) for i in suffix]:
                row.append(fields) #WRONG

        writer.writerows(all)
```

The code above just adds a new columns to the file (out): I know that there is something wrong in the for loop, when I check the suffix.

Could you please help me to fix the code properly and explain me how to check the values?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A simple way is to add an inner for-loop to iterate over the possible suffixes and check each.

Comment: @MichaelButscher, I updated the code (and the question) including a `for loop` to check if an element ends with a suffix in the list suffix:  `if [row[0].endswith(i) for i in suffix]`. However, it does not return me the corresponding field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function to create a sequence of suffix and field pairs that can be used to check for a matching suffix and know the corresponding field to append. There's also no reason to create all the rows first and then output them because the processing can be done incrementally, row-by-row.

Here's what I mean:

```
import csv

UNKNOWN = 'UNKNOWN'
suffixes = ['_pol', '_econ', '_sport', '_maths', '_computerscience', 'others']
fields = ['politics', 'economics', 'sports', 'mathematics', 'computer science', 'others']
pairs = tuple(zip(suffixes, fields))

with open('./parsed.csv', 'r', newline='') as csvinput, \
     open('./parsed_out.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvoutput:

    reader = csv.reader(csvinput)
    writer = csv.writer(csvoutput, lineterminator='\n')

    header = next(reader)
    header.append('Subjects')
    writer.writerow(header)

    for row in reader:
        match = [UNKNOWN]
        for suffix, field in pairs:
            if row[0].endswith(suffix):
                match[0] = field
                break
        writer.writerow(row + match)

print('Done')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
for row in reader:
    field = None
    for (s,f) in zip(suffix, fields):
        if row[0].endswith(s):
            field = f
            break
```

Comment: thank you @MjZac. How can I write in the file output only the 'fields'?